# What change should I make in my current resume before submitting it for Graduate school transfer application?

Tags: graduate-admissions, cv, transfer-student

I will be completing my first semester at a Graduate school in 3 months and I have planned to take a transfer to another school in Fall semester. I need to update my current resume that I need to send along with the transfer graduate school application. So what changes can I make to my existing resume.

What all things should I mention about my current school and where should I mention this information in the resume.

Can anyone provide me some resource that would be helpful for resume writing for transfer application?

Comment: Update it in the same way you would for anything else. There is nothing special about transferring in regard to your resume.

Answer (score 3):

The main change that you should make is to change from a *resume* to a *curriculum vitae*, which is the standard academic equivalent.  [Here is a good resource explaining the difference](http://writingcenter.unc.edu/handouts/curricula-vitae-cvs-versus-resumes/).